# ImageButton behind ImageView and offset

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

So I'm working on making a design for my app and I need to put a imagebutton directly below an imageview. But since my imageview has a border around it with a drop shadow I need to hide (shift up) maybe 10 pixels of my imagebutton behind my imageview. Here is a quick drawing of what I want.

[image: Example]

I hope that makes sense. I've been messing around with all kinds of different arrangements but I cant get what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very good example photo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all use a `RelativeLayout`. Add first the `ImageButton` and then the `ImageView`, in this way the `ImageView` will be on top of your `ImageButton`. Then you should set on your `ImageButton` the following :

```
<ImageButton
    ....
    android:layout_below="@id/ImageViewId"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10px" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Only change was that I had to do "@+id/ImageViewId" Thanks alot for the quick reply.

Comment: RelativeLayout is the way to go, you saved me a headache

Answer (score 2):

Use relative layout as said. Refer
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html
 for more positions and easy design.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Imageview"
    android:layout_marginTop="-16dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/imagename" />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is going to place the button on top of the image :)