# Placing text view over an image view using FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

Below is how I have designed my xml. Now what I am trying to fit a textview inside the white box shown below. But am being restricted by FrameLayout (at least I think so) that I need to hard code values to make the text view fit in the middle or some where inside the white box. I cannot use Relative or other layouts for this purpose as I have understood by my trials as this whole is a single image.

Here is my layout,

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/xxx">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/calloutquizImage" 
        android:background="@drawable/callout" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/triviaImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/calloutquizImage" android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/trivia" android:background="@drawable/trivia"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip" android:layout_marginLeft="85dip"></ImageView>

    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/triviAnswerText"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dip" android:layout_marginLeft="85dip"
        android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="sans"></TextView>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/triviaanswercloseButton"
        android:src="@drawable/closebtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/closebtn"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip" android:layout_marginTop="43dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right" android:onClick="triviaanswerClose"></ImageButton>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/buttontoclose"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:visibility="visible" android:onClick="triviaanswerClose" 
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip" android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
        android:layout_width="230dip" android:layout_height="170dip"></ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Because of this the text view looks in different positions in various handsets.

Any guesses what can be done for this instead?

Below is my image :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you are not doing the right thing. If you want a text to appear inside a white box (or even resize it, if there is to many text to fit to it) - you can still avoid any layouts ad do  it with **only one** TextView.

Please have a look what is **`NinePatch`** image in Android:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html - drawing tools

So basically you will need only 1 textView and your image, properly converted to 9-patch with 2nd link. (Basically - just add a few black pixels on image border).
No just set this 9-patch as a background of textView. It will place text right where you need, and will shrink white box if you'll define so in 9-patch.

**UPD:** 
Please find the resulting screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, textView not handles 
WhiteBox" itself, filling it with text and resizing the box if necessary.

Here is how to make it work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Manymanymany text 
        Manymanymany text 
        Manymanymany text 
        Manymanymany text 
        Manymanymany text 
        Manymanymany text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/first"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not so many text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is your image, converted to 9patch. Just place it to "drawable/" folder. Note: it MUST have "back.9.png" name.
[image]

For details of how 9patch works you can check links above. The main idea: by making black dots on left and top border - you specify which part of the image will be stretched when image must be upscaled. By making dots on right/bottom side you tell the View where to place the content. In our case content is a text of the TextView.

Hope it helps, good luck

Comment: AlexN, can you explain me little more if you don't mind. I cannot understand how this 9-patch works. I would be even great if you can just give me some lines of code.

Comment: Yep, give me a second, I'm not very familiar with Paint :)

Comment: Please find an answer updated. By the way, in RelativeLayout you still can manage order of Views in Z axis - views are just placed on top of each other in order of declaration inside <RalativeLayout> tag. However, 9patch is much more flexible and efficient solution in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately I want the white box to retain its size. And how come the text is appearing inside the box for you! It is starting from outside the box for me :(

Comment: Did you used a modified image that I'd attached, with black dots? Did you name it 'back.9.png' inside of /drawable/? .9 is really important

Comment: Yes I have used that image only and that time I had named it just back.png but now after changing also I couldn't see any changes :( The text starts above the box ( from left top most side )

Comment: I'd updated the image, can you please try once again? I suspect one pixel was wrong-placed on previous one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a `RelativeLayout` within the `FrameLayout` for the `ImageView` and the `TextView`, and by using the parameters, you can navigate the `TextView` to the white box.  Refer to the [LayoutParams documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for details.

for eg. you can add the `ImageView` block first and then the `TextView`, so that the `TextView` will lay over the `ImageView`, and by using align bottom, and specifying top margin with a negative value, you can make the `TextView` go over the image. Or rather, if you are using eclipse, you can directly move the text view in the graphic layout.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margintop="0dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/user2" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Textviewtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            app:context=".TestActivity" />

    </RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Similar to above, you can specify margin left and right to properly position your `TextView` as you want. Check with graphic layout for feedback to know the correct position. 
Please reply if this helped.

Use your images and values for the height and width. I just tried for testing.

Comment: Nayanan, Is it possible? Because in relative layout we can specify objects in relation to each other right, not over another  object. When i tried this, I could not do this. For eg, I cannot use left of or right of properties here as I believe.

Comment: Please see the edit. it worked. I have used this many times. :).

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" this places text view below the white box not inside white box

Comment: yes. now use the marginTop value to navigate it over the image!!! tht is why i have given the negative value. please try the code and then comment. Dont just comment after compiling it just by seeing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231138/imagebutton-behind-imageview-and-offset

please see this question. its almost the same case. instead of imagebuttom, it is a textview.

Comment: I have commented after seeing what I got. Even I don't have time to comment unnecessary stuffs here, hope you got that. I asked a help does not mean that I comment useless things

Comment: And I thank you for your answer, but mean while I cannot tolerate alegations

Comment: lol. i did not allegate boss. it worked smoothly for me. I dunno wat ur missing. anyways, sry if u took it hard.. try 2 take it easy! :).